# Apply row-wise transformation in R so that total percentage for each row will be 100%

Tags: r, transformation

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- structure(list(groups= c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"), 
                 A = c(28.6, 26.7, 29.1,23.1,1.0),
                 B = c(24.5, 22.3,23.9,20.2,1.5),
                 C = c(12.1,11.2,12.1,11.7,1.5),
                 D = c(9.4,7.0,9.0,8.7,1.1)),
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c("1","2","3","4"))


   groups     A       B      C      D  

1  group1   28.6    24.5    12.1   9.4
2  group2   26.7    22.3    11.2   7.0
3  group3   29.1    23.9    12.1   9.0
4  group4   23.1    20.2    11.7   8.7
```

The values in the dataframe are in percentage. I would like to grow the total percent for each row to be 100%. So the output would look similar like this(BTW, I calculated the expected output by hand, so it may not be so accurate as computer calculated):

```
 groups     A       B      C      D  

1  group1   38.3    32.8    16.2   12.6
2  group2   39.7    33.1    16.7   10.4
3  group3   39.7    32.6    16.4   11.3
4  group4   36.3    31.5    18.9   13.3
```

How should I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `proportions` to get *percentages*.

```
proportions(as.matrix(df[1:4,-1]), 1) * 100
#         A        B        C        D
#1 38.33780 32.84182 16.21984 12.60054
#2 39.73214 33.18452 16.66667 10.41667
#3 39.27126 32.25371 16.32928 12.14575
#4 36.26374 31.71115 18.36735 13.65777
```

Comment: Thanks@GKI, I like the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in the dplyr context:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sm = sum(c_across(-groups))) %>% 
  mutate(across(A:D, function(x)x/sm)*100) %>% 
  select(-sm)
## A tibble: 5 x 5
## Rowwise: 
#  groups     A     B     C     D
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 group1  38.3  32.8  16.2  12.6
#2 group2  39.7  33.2  16.7  10.4
#3 group3  39.3  32.3  16.3  12.1
#4 group4  36.3  31.7  18.4  13.7
#5 group5  19.6  29.4  29.4  21.6
```

Comment: Thank you @DaveArmstrong. I selected GKi's solution because is shorter. But from your answer, I see how to do similar type of transformations in the future. Thank you:)